# Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir error on interactionCreate

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fs

All of my files from `Commands` are read in fine but I get an error from 'interactionCreate.js`located in`Events`

```
node:internal/fs/utils:343
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir './Events/interactionCreate.js'
```

My `Event.js` file is as follows:

```js
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');
let table = new ascii("Events");
table.setHeading('EVENTS', ' LOAD STATUS');

module.exports = (client) => {
    readdirSync('./Events/').forEach(dir => {
        const events = readdirSync(`./Events/${dir}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for(let file of events) {
            let pull = require(`../Events/${dir}/${file}`);
            if(pull.name) {
                client.events.set(pull.name, pull);
            } else {
                table.addRow(file, 'EVENT REGISTERED')
                continue;
            } if(pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))
        }
    });
    console.log(table.toString());
}
```

Comment: That line of code and that error message don't match. `./Commands` != `./Events`. There's something you're not showing us. Regardless, `interactionCreate.js` is indeed not a directory; don't try to read it with `readdirSync`

Comment: @mpen, thanks for letting me know. I've updated the question and figured out it was an issue with `fs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    readdirSync('./Events/').forEach(dir => {
        const events = readdirSync(`./Events/${dir}`)
```

`readdirSync` will return *all* the entries in the `Events` dir, that includes both files and directories. You've named your variable `dir` but they aren't all dirs. This is evidenced by the error message which specifically states `./Events/interactionCreate.js` is not a directory.

Either remove non-dirs from your `Events` directory (i.e. move that file), or better, check if `dir` is in fact a directory before calling `readdirSync` on it.

The easiest way to do that is to add the `{withFileTypes: true}` option, and then you can call `dir.isDirectory()`

See docs https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options